Is there any way that I can access my router when internet connection sharing?
I have a computer that is connected through WiFi. I am sharing this connection using Windows Internet Connection sharing via Ethernet port to wan port on router. The router has another PC connected to it through one of the lan ports also getting internet from pc 1. Essentially I’m trying to use NDI for OBS and I want to stream the display from pc 1 to pc 2. I know it works when pc 2 is connected to the same WiFi as pc 1 but when doing so it causes too much congestion on the apartments access point which is why I’m trying to find this workaround.

This is a needlessly complicated setup network-wise. Replace the router with a switch, or set it to switch mode or bridge mode or the closest thing that exists. It will just pass through the connection without changing and you won't need to access the router.

@crit maybe OP only has a router to use as a switch?   If exactly two computers, then OP could get away with an ethernet cable between the two machines and do away with the router.

if your router doesn't have a switch mode/bridge mode, you can turn off DHCP, make sure the router's IP address doesn't conflict with your network (different network number is preferable e.g. 192.168.2.1) and use only the LAN ports - do not plug anything into the WAN port.

Yes, you can still access your router while using Windows Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) through Ethernet. When you connect PC 1 via Wi-Fi and share the internet to the router’s WAN port using ICS, the router should still be accessible through the LAN ports. However, to avoid network conflicts, ensure that the router's IP range is different from the one used by ICS, which typically assigns a 192.168.137.x subnet. You can change your router's IP to something like 192.168.0.1 to avoid any overlap. Additionally, make sure your router is not causing Double NAT by setting it to Bridge Mode or Access Point Mode, which disables its NAT and allows it to function as a simple switch. This setup will enable both PC 1 and PC 2 to communicate via Ethernet while avoiding Wi-Fi congestion. Finally, to use NDI for OBS, ensure both PCs are on the same subnet and that PC 2, connected via Ethernet, can stream from PC 1 without any network bottlenecks.

The most likely problem is probably that your router is creating its own separate subnet on the LAN side, which would cause issues with device discovery needed by NDI.
But the way you can connect PC 1 and PC 2 on the same subnet for uncongested NDI streaming is by is by switching your router to access point mode and connecting PC 1’s Ethernet to one of the router's LAN ports instead of the WAN port.
The reason for doing this is because setting the router to AP mode disables its (problematic) separate IP subnet and allows it to function as a bridge, as opposed to creating a whole new network.
